# VSCode AngularJS intellisense

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

So with the new language service Salsa nearing completion (Available in `1.8.0-insider` with a few environment variables set) You can get intellisense support with `jsDoc` comments. This is thanks to TypeScripts support for it.

However my issue is continuing that into an AngularJS service, or controller for custom types. Just to note this is for JavaScript code, not TypeScript.

Let me quickly demonstrate my setup to hopefully explain.

I define my services, controller etc as CommonJS modules (To enable framework independent code reuse, and easier organisation)

```
//service.js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} someObj
 * @prop {int} value
 */

/**
 * Do some action
 * @param {string} val
 * @returns {someObj}
 */
exports.test = function(val) {
    return {};
}
```

When i `require` this anywhere in my project VSCode picks up the JSdoc comments and gives me correct intellisense, brilliant.

So traditionally i would plug that into angular like:

```
angular.module('myModule').service('service', () => require('./service'));
```

Now is where my wonderful new intellisense dreams are crushed.
Understandably when i inject that service anywhere all intellisense is lost as VSCode nor TypeScript can be expected to understand the intricacies or every frameworks DI systems.

So I'm left a little stumped.

I had the thought of creating typing's just for the angular wrappers around my services, controllers. However upon researching it i couldn't find anyway of getting the types defined in the world of JSDoc into my definition files (I'm not a TypeScript guy).

I also had the thought of using `@module` syntax of jsDoc to define all my CommonJs services, controllers etc. Then using that module to set the type of each function parameter where I'm injecting in my custom modules, However I'm not entirely sure that would work looking at the docs. It seems you have to specify your `@module` tag with the path expected in your `require` call which wouldn't work with relatively required modules where that path would change. Nor does the docs mention being able to use it in the `@Param` tag to say `this variable is this module`.

The other option i considered was some extension that helps VSCode's intellisense by providing the missing link. Consume the known intellisense info when defining the service and passing it onto the instances where that service is injected. However i couldn't find any such extension, nor even if it would be possible to create.

With the advances in VSCode's intellisense thanks to Salsa and typescript is this at all possible? I had got my hopes up with the JSDoc support, but i guess too soon.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, that or any workarounds where i could change my way of working slightly to get the desired result.

Comment: Not an answer, but a question: I'm using Angular 1x, VSCode, and want JSDoc intellisense. Did you get anywhere with this? Should I give up or is there a solution?

Comment: @PhilRicketts Bad news, i gave up. You could go down the route of custom TypeScript typings but my project doesn't have the available time to invest. I went against JSDoc as for me it caused far too much noise and i couldn't see the code through it. In the end i went to maintaining quality markdown documentation of all the external API's to my modules. Have a little node task that will fire up a small file server when i need to quickly reference them. Sorry can't be of more help.

Comment: Some more information, I discovered that Typescript is able to convert JSDoc comments into typings. So the issue now is marrying up file locations.